Passing a parameter to a resource control in XAML
I have a button defined as a resource within a ControlTemplate in order to be able to use it more than once.
<Grid.Resources>
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="GenericButton">
       <Button Text="Click Here"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ViewModelProperty,
                           Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullConverter}}" />
   </ControlTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>

I would like the button to be a little more dynamic and receive the ViewModelProperty as a parameter instead, through another XAML Control.
Currently, I'm displaying the resource button in this fashion (which works fine as long as the ViewModelProperty name is concretely spelled out as seen in the above code):
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="20" Spacing="20" VerticalOptions="Fill">
   <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource GenericButton}" />
</VerticalStackLayout>

Instead, I would like to do something like this:
<ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource GenericButton, Parameter=ViewModelProperty}" />

And the resource button would look something like this:
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GenericButton">
   <Button Text="Click Here"
            IsEnabled="{Binding PassedViewModelPropertyParameter,
                       Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullConverter}}" />
</ControlTemplate>

What is that concept of passing a parameter between Controls called? And how to approach this problem?

Since you are using a Control template you should be using a TemplateBinding instead of a regular Binding
More information here
 <Button Text="Click Here"
                IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding SelectedItemProperty,
                           Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullConverter}}" />


I might not have been clear about this. But my main intention was to find a way to pass a ViewModel's property to the resource Button through the ContentView Control. Even though binding the ViewModel property to the ContentView IsEnabled property first, then binding the Button's IsEnabled property to the IsEnabled property of the ContentView does work, something doesn't seem natural about this.

About Control template and TemplateBinding, you can check this code sample: .net MAUI DataTemplate's. Command Bindings in Parents View Model.
